# Get characters of a string starting from last part of string up to a period

Tags: twig

I have an array with such strings as:

```
filename.pdf
filename.xls
filename.txt
filename.ppt
```

How can I grab the string, start at last part of the string and work my way up to the immediate period, so that I can determine `.pdf` and '.xls`and`.ppt` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html), which uses [explode](https://secure.php.net/explode) in the background and return the last element,

*data*

```
data:
    - filename.pdf
    - filename.xls
    - filename.txt
    - filename.ppt
```

*twig*

```
{% for file in data %}
    {{ file | split('.') | last }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/focgff)